# Function to replicate rows of dataframe if column contains list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, replicate

I am not sure the best way to title this. If I have a dataframe and one of the columns, lets call it 'Tags', may contain a list or may not. If 'Tags' is a list, then I want to replicate that row as many times as there are unique items in the 'Tags' column but then replace the items in that column with the unique item for each row.

Example:

```python
import pandas as pd 

# create dummy dataframe
df = {'Date': ['2020-10-28'],
      'Item': 'My_fake_item',
      'Tags': [['A', 'B']],
      'Count': 3}

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Date', 'Item', 'Tags', 'Count'])
```

Would result in:
[image: Original Dataframe]

And I need a function that will change the dataframe to this:
[image: New Dataframe]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the `explode` method, for example

```
df_exploded = (
        df.set_index(["Date", "Item", "Count"])
        .apply(pd.Series.explode)
        .reset_index()
    )
```

will result in

```
df_exploded
>>>
    Date        Item         Count  Tags
0   2020-10-28  My_fake_item    3   A
1   2020-10-28  My_fake_item    3   B
```

and there's no need to check if an element is a list or not on the column

```
import pandas as pd 

# create dummy dataframe
df = {'Date': ['2020-10-28', '2020-11-01'],
      'Item': ['My_fake_item', 'My_other_item'],
      'Tags': [['A', 'B'], 'C'],
      'Count': [3, 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Date', 'Item', 'Tags', 'Count'])
```

will result in

```
          Date  Item          Count Tags
0   2020-10-28  My_fake_item    3   A
1   2020-10-28  My_fake_item    3   B
2   2020-11-01  My_other_item   5   C
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm. I had never seen that method before.